# Fast query and deletion of documents of a large collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, delete-file

I have a collection (let say CollOne) with several million documents. They have the common field "id"

```
{...,"id":1}
{...,"id":2}
```

I need to delete some documents in CollOne by id. Those ids stored in a document in another collection (CollTwo). This ids_to_delete document has the structure as follows

```
{"action_type":"toDelete","ids":[4,8,9,....]}
```

As CollOne is quite large, finding and deleting one document will take quite a long time. Is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can't really avoid a deletion operation in the database if you want to delete anything. If you're having performance issue I would just recommend to make sure you have an index built on the `id` field otherwise Mongo will use a `COLLSCAN` to satisfy the query which means it will over iterate the entire `colLOne` collection which is I guess where you feel the pain.

Once you make sure an index is built there is no "more" efficient way than using `deleteMany`.

```
db.collOne.deleteMany({id: {$in: [4, 8, 9, .... ]})
```

- In case you don't have an index and wonder how to build one, you should use [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) like so:
  (Prior to version 4.2 building an index lock the entire database, in large scale this could take up to several hours if not more, to avoid this use the `background` option)

```
db.collOne.createIndex({id: 1})
```

---- EDIT ----

In Mongo shell:

Mongo shell is javascript based, so you just have to to execute the same logic with js syntax, here's how I would do it:

```
let toDelete = db.collTwo.findOne({ ... })
db.collOne.deleteMany({id: {$in: toDelete.ids}})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Really saved me a lot of time. I also wonder if there is a way to replace [4,8,9,...,] in $in field with some reference to the ids_to_delete document? something like {$in : CollTwo.find({"action_type":"toDelete"}).field("ids")}. I use Python, so I can query the two collections separately and get the deletion job done. But I just wonder if I can just use Mongo-shell to do it. Sorry if this question is very basic.

Comment: Yes ofcourse there is, are you using `pymongo` or the native mongo package?

Comment: I use pymongo. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I mean I know how to use pymongo to finish the task (e.g., put a list to the $in field). But how to do it in the Mongo-shell? Thanks!

Comment: Mongo shell is javascript based but the "logic" you want to execute remains the same, I edited it an example of how to execute these two in the shell.